# Python cryptography.x509 backend parameter, required or not?

Tags: python, cryptography, x509, client-certificates

I'm reading in client certificates using Python cryptography.x509.

The docs [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#loading-certificates) say the `backend` parameter is `optional`:

```
Parameters: 

    data (bytes) – The PEM encoded certificate data.
    backend – An optional backend supporting the X509Backend interface.
```

However when I try to load a `pem` file, it fails stating the `backend` property is required:

[image]

**What am I missing here?**

**EDIT1:**

- The latest version I see for cryptography is 3.1.1:

[image]

- After installing 3.1.1, for some reason, I'm only able to use 2.8:

[image]

- In this notebook, I'm using Python 3.8... so how is this addressed?

[image]

**EDIT2: I just had to close and reopen the notebook after installing 3.1.1!

- Now the `backend` parameter is optional.

Comment: It was my mistake (I edited my answer) - latest release is 3.1.1, and 3.2. is still under development. Obviously you have more than one python version or virtual environment. And please, don't post images, copy/paste code, error, output as text and properly formated.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you are using older version. Check the [changelog](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/changelog/#v3-1) - `backend` is optional since ver.3.1. (2020-08-26)

> `backend` arguments to functions are no longer required and the default
> backend will automatically be selected if no backend is provided.

Current version is 3.1.1. (EDIT: ver. 3.2 is still under developmnet)